# How to move a 3D object in godot with mouse coordinations with?

Tags: 3d, mouseevent, game-engine, game-development, godot

I'm encountering a problem using godot engine with GDscript, (but if you know the answer with other godot languages, I welcome those answers too!  )

Assume that my object is a *ball*. The specific action I want to make with my mouse is:

If I move my mouse to the **right**: the **3D object** would move to the **right**

If I move my mouse to the **left**: the **3D object** would move to the **left**

If I move my mouse  **up**: the **3D object** would move **forward**

If I move my mouse  **down**: the **3D object** would move  **backward**

I'd be thanked if you guide me to how to write the script! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `_input` function for that. It receives an event, which you can check for if it is an `InputEventMouseMouseMotion`. Then you can use `event.relative` to move the ball in the direction.